# Angular 5 view child reference not working in Safari (v 11.1)

Tags: javascript, angular, safari, angular5

I have a simple file input which I want to access using `ElementRef` and `@ViewChild` and upload an image to the server.

I got the following solution that's working perfectly in the last versions of Chrome and Firefox but is not working in Safari (v11.1).

The problem is that in Safari, the ElementRef to the input contains no file.
When I console log the `this.el.nativeElement.files.length` on the change action the result of this is -1 in Safari and 1 in Chrome or Firefox. Any idea about this issue?

```
<input #fileInput (change)="fileUpload()" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

In the component class, I reference the file input using `ViewChild`.

```
 import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core'
 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
     <div>
      <form class="row" [formGroup]="changeAvatar" novalidate (ngSubmit)="sendChangeAvatarForm()">
            <input #fileInput 
                 formControlName="avatar" 
                 (change)="fileUpload()" 
                 type="file" 
                 name="pic" 
                 accept="image/*">
      </form>
   </div>
  `,
 })
 export class App {
  @ViewChild('fileInput') el:ElementRef;
  constructor() {
  } 
  get avatar() {
     return this.el.nativeElement.files[0];
  }
  fileUpload() {
    // Access the uploaded file through the ElementRef
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.files.length);
    // http request to the backend with the file this.el.nativeElement.files[0]; 
  }
}
```

I'm using Angular client 1.7.4 and Angular 5.2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to uplaod files in angular you have to use $event object to get files

**HTML**

```
  <input  (change)="fileUpload($event.target.files) type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```

**TS**

```
   fileUpload(files: File[]){
    console.log(files)
    var formData = new FormData();
    Array.from(files).forEach(f => formData.append('file',f))

    this.http.post('https://file.io', formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          this.uploadSuccess = true;
        }
    });
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-cszfpp